# Swift array split in overlapping chunks

Tags: arrays, swift

I'm trying to figure out how to split an array into overlapping chunks.

As an example, this is the input:

`[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]`

and this is the expected output (chunk size is 3):

`[[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5], [4, 5, 6], [5, 6, 7], [6, 7, 8], [7, 8, 9], [8, 9, 10]]`

I started out using stride (via Hacking With Swift):

```
extension Array {
    func chunked(into size: Int) -> [[Element]] {
        return stride(from: 0, to: count, by: size).map {
            Array(self[$0 ..< Swift.min($0 + size, count)])
        }
    }
}
```

Which of course gives this incorrect output:

`[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10]]`

I couldn't find any variation of `stride` to get the expected result, so just did this, using two nested `for-loops`:

```
extension Array {
    func chunked2(into size: Int) -> [[Element]] {
        var result: [[Element]] = []
        
        for i in 0...self.count {
            var chunk: [Element] = []
           
            for j in i..<i+size {
                if j < self.count {
                    chunk.append(self[j])
                }
            }
        
            if chunk.count == size {
                result.append(chunk)
            }
        }
        
        return result
    }
}
```

This works and gives the expected result.

Question: I am wondering if I can rewrite this in a more "Swifty" way, using functions like `stride`, `map`, maybe `reduce` or something else I am missing?

Comment: `stride()` allows you to do a for loop with another increment that 1. But here, you want to increment by one. So I don't think that `stride` is the correct method here. A simple loop from 0 to "count - size" should do the trick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're describing is called "windowing." It's very common in digital signal processing, and is available out of the box in [swift-algorithms](https://github.com/apple/swift-algorithms/blob/main/Guides/Windows.md). For more about the swift-algorithms package, and its role in the Swift ecosystem, see [Announcing Swift Algorithms](https://www.swift.org/blog/swift-algorithms/).

If you want to see an example of how the algorithm works, check out [the source](https://github.com/apple/swift-algorithms/blob/main/Sources/Algorithms/Windows.swift). They achieve it using a data structure, WindowsOfCountCollection, rather than creating a bunch of zips, etc. This is often more efficient, since the windows are generated on-demand, and don't have to allocate a bunch of memory up-front.

Comment: `import Algorithms` and `myArray.windows(ofCount: 3)` does the trick. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**"I am wondering if I can rewrite this in a more "Swifty" way, using functions like stride, map, maybe reduce or something else I am missing?"**.

Yes, you can create your own method using collection `func sequence<T, State>(state: State, next: @escaping (inout State) -> T?) -> UnfoldSequence<T, State>` method as follow:

```
extension Collection {
    func windows(of count: Int) -> UnfoldSequence<SubSequence,Index> {
        sequence(state: startIndex) { start in
            guard start < endIndex,
                let end = index(
                    start,
                    offsetBy: count,
                    limitedBy: endIndex
                )
            else { return nil }
            defer { formIndex(after: &start) }
            return self[start..<end]
        }
    }
}
```

---

Usage:

```
let numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
let windows = numbers.windows(of: 3)
for window in windows {
    print(window)
}
```

This will print:

> [1, 2, 3]
> [2, 3, 4]
> [3, 4, 5]
> [4, 5, 6]
> [5, 6, 7]
> [6, 7, 8]
> [7, 8, 9]
> [8, 9, 10]

Note that the elements of the resulting sequence are computed lazily. It will return an UnfoldSequence without duplicating the original elements.

If you need to output an array of sub sequences you can do as follow:

```
extension Collection {
    func windows(of count: Int) -> [SubSequence] {
        .init(sequence(state: startIndex) { start in
            guard start < endIndex,
                let end = index(
                    start,
                    offsetBy: count,
                    limitedBy: endIndex
                )
            else { return nil }
            defer { formIndex(after: &start) }
            return self[start..<end]
        })
    }
}
```

If you really need to duplicate the resulting elements and output an array of arrays:

```
extension Collection  {
    func windows(of count: Int) -> [[Element]] {
        .init(sequence(state: startIndex) { start in
            guard start < endIndex,
                let end = index(
                    start,
                    offsetBy: count,
                    limitedBy: endIndex
                )
            else { return nil }
            defer { formIndex(after: &start) }
            return .init(self[start..<end])
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`stride()` is more or less a for loop with other increment than 1. But here, you want to iterate on each element (ie, increment by 1), and take the next n elements with it.

I found the question interesting, so here are "two" other ways.

Array have indices, so you can use them, and sometimes, we tend to forget about them (about `indices` value, `someArray[index]` is used every time).

I use `compactMap()` in the first solution. It's more or less a simple loop for. Its little downside, is that if your array has n elements, it will iterate n times, instead of "n - size".
I use `map` in the second solution. It's more or less a simple loop for. I calculate before and the "end", avoiding the unecessary iterations as in the previous solution.
You could combine mix both ideas if needed.
It's unclear what to do with limit sizes, like 0, size > count, etc, so I've left the logs as such.

```
extension Array {
    func windows(size: Int) -> [[Element]] {
        indices.compactMap { anElement in
            let end = anElement.advanced(by: size)
            guard end <= count else { return nil }
            return Array(self[anElement ..< end])
        }
    }

    func windows2(size: Int) -> [[Element]] {
        guard size <= count else { return [] } //We check before, else, the next line will crash
        let end = indices.upperBound.advanced(by: -size)
        return (indices.lowerBound...end).map {
            Array(self[$0..<$0.advanced(by: size)])
        }
    }
}
```

Play testing:

```
let initialArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

print("Window: 3") //"Normal" behavior
print(initialArray.windows(size: 3))
print(initialArray.windows2(size: 3))
print("Window: 10") //Size = count
print(initialArray.windows(size: 10))
print(initialArray.windows2(size: 10))
print("Window: 0") //No size
print(initialArray.windows(size: 0))
print(initialArray.windows2(size: 0))
print("Window: 1") //Size of 1
print(initialArray.windows(size: 1))
print(initialArray.windows2(size: 1))
print("Window: 11") //Window greater than the count
print(initialArray.windows(size: 11))
print(initialArray.windows2(size: 11))
```

Output:

```
Window: 3
[[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5], [4, 5, 6], [5, 6, 7], [6, 7, 8], [7, 8, 9], [8, 9, 10]]
[[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5], [4, 5, 6], [5, 6, 7], [6, 7, 8], [7, 8, 9], [8, 9, 10]]
Window: 10
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]]
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]]
Window: 0
[[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]
[[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []] //Here there is a differenccec
Window: 1
[[1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10]]
[[1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10]]
Window: 11
[]
[]
```